# R class been removed by Eclipse after Clean Project

Tags: android, eclipse

This is the weirdest thing I've seen in Eclipse. When I ran my Android project, I forgot to select the Main view class and the one selected was the `main.xml`, so as you may know I got the file `main.out.xml` generated by Eclipse. To solve this, I selected "Project > Clean," but after that my `R` class under `gen/` disappeared. Does anyone know how to get it back and/or how to avoid this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you ticked "Project > Build Automatically" ?

Comment: If yes, then what does "Right click on your project folder > Android Tools > Fix Project Properties" do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R class is generated each time you recompile the project(if changes are necessary), and you shouldn't bother yourself about it. More over, you shouldn't even commit R file to your version control system, as it should be generated while the build process.

I advise you to set the checkbox "compile before running"(eclipse should have it in run configuration) checked, so the R file will be regenerated before you run the app.

Comment: problem solved. I had to copy the R class from another project to be able to run the project, then it compiled the R class and generated the right ids. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is well known for such issues. If Project > Clean doesn't help, try to restart the IDE.

I do recommend to use IntelliJ IDEA though - I've been using Eclipse for years before, then switched to IntelliJ, what a relief...

http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/10/intellij-idea-10-free-ide-for-android-development/

Comment: in my one year experience as a Java programmer it feels sad to leave my school partner Eclipse ;( but if i have to change IDE there's nothing to it

Comment: You don't have to switch, Eclipse does work, you should just be aware of the known issues that come with it. No IDE is perfect, I'm just stating my subjective experience with it, which is why I'd personally choose IntelliJ over NetBeans over Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Add some file to resource, that will force Eclipse regenerate R class.